# How to append text to an bytearray

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am working with **python 3** and have a text file which I put in a string variable and then create an **byte array** like this:

```
file = open('labb9Text.txt', "r")
for lines in file:
    txt = str(lines)
    byteArr = bytearray(txt, 'utf-8')
```

Now I want to retrieve that variable outside the for loop. I have tried doing like this:

```
byteArr = bytearray()

file = open('labb9Text.txt', "r")
for lines in file:
    txt = str(lines)
    byteArr = bytearray(txt, 'utf-8')

print(byteArr)
```

But this does not work, the byteArr is empty. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works correctly, but only in a very literal sense. Why is `byteArr` empty after running that loop? Because inside the loop, you are setting it to the contents of every single line *in turn*, and the very last line must be empty. So you get a valid result for your last line only.

You correctly create a variable `byteArr` before the loop, but inside the loop you must *add* the new bytes, not replace them.

A few more notes: in `lines in file..` the variable `lines` is already a string, so `txt = str(lines)` is not necessary. It's generally neater to use `with` to open a file, because it also automatically *closes* it at the end of that code block (and indeed it's something you forgot to do here).

```py
byteArr = bytearray()

with open('labb9Text.txt', "r") as file:
    for lines in file:
        byteArr += bytearray(lines, 'utf-8')
print (byteArr)
```

---

As things go, this can even be done much easier, but only if that encoding `utf-8` is not really necessary (that is, if the file already is in the correct encoding):

```py
with open('labb9Text.txt', "rb") as file:
    byteArray = bytearray(file.read())
```

It doesn't need any loop at all.